# Supporting node and es-module style imports for typescript package

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a project that I am converting from JS (transpiled via babel) to Typescript. The module consists of a single function and uses an `module.exports = myFunction` to set it as the default.

The issue that I've run into is that I'd like to preserve `require` format for `node` users:

```
const myModule = require('my-module')
```

still allow es module aware users (typescript/babel) to `import`:

```
import myModule from 'my-module'
```

I've seen the [`typescript-library-starter`](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter) which has a separate build process using `rollup` to emit UMDified version of the module that translates the `module.exports.default = myModule` to a node style `module.exports = myModule` but I'd prefer not to have to include an entirely separate build system for server side code (this is server only, so there's no great need for the tree-shaking/compression that rollup provides).

Currently, I can do something like the following

```
export = myFunction
```

which will support the `const myModule = require('my-module')` use case, but means that TS/es module users will need to do something like:

```
import * as myModule from 'my-module'
```

or drop back to a simple `const myModule = require('my-module')` (which removes the benefits of typescript).

Is there a pattern to distribute my module that works for both node style requires and es-module style imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get a great answer to this so I ended up using `export =` and `import = require`

```
// index.ts
function myModule () {}

export = myModule
```

Node users can use a regular `require` and typescript users can use a mix of `import` and require to get type safety:

```
// consumer.ts
import myModule = require('my-module')
```

Which is a pattern I gleaned from the[Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require):

> When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module.

You can see this "live" in my [protractor-flake](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/blob/master/src/index.ts#L94) module.